# How to full reindex in Magento via backend admin page?

Tags: magento-enterprise, reindex

I am using latest version of Magento enterprise 1.14, however it doesnt allow to do full reindex in admin "index management".

Our staff need to import products frequently and he is not technical enough to run shell command to reindex.
Is there any quick fix or hack to make it enable in backend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved.

On the admin reindex controller, you have to add a new event for triggering new reindex mechanism.

> Mage::dispatchEvent($process->getIndexerCode() .
>   '_shell_reindex_after');

I found this code in the ***shell/reindex.php*** which can reindex successfully by command line.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this article "http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing". IT has all the information you need for the reindexing purpose